# How Scrapy extract text inside class that inside attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have an HTML code below :

```html
<div 
      class="hero-data__skills-item hero-data__skills-item-passive J-tooltip" 
      title='<div class="tootip">
                <div class="tootip-name">Royal Power</div>
                <div class="tootip-desc">Ketika HP Thane turun di bawah 30%, dia memulihkan 24% dari Max HP-nya selama 6 detik. Cooldown 75 detik.</div>
             </div>'>

</div>
```

Using this code, I can extract title attribute :

```
response.css('.hero-data__skills-item::attr(title)').extract_first()
```

And then I get this code from title attribute :

```
<div class="tootip"><div class="tootip-name">Royal Power</div><div class="tootip-desc">Ketika HP Thane turun di bawah 30%, dia memulihkan 24% dari Max HP-nya selama 6 detik. Cooldown 75 detik.</div></div>
```

I want to extract the text inside **tooltip-name** class inside title attribute, so I will get **Royal Power**,

how can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a separate `Selector` over any text:

```
outer = response.css('.hero-data__skills-item::attr(title)').extract_first()
sel = Selector(text=outer)
name = sel.css('.tooltip-name::text').get()
```

Comment: Thank you Apalala, you save my life...!