# Scrapy how to extract the text of the field that you are not selecting on

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to python/scrapy.  My question is similar to this question, but I can't quite craft an answer that works:

[How Scrapy extract text inside class that inside attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663463/how-scrapy-extract-text-inside-class-that-inside-attribute)

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='indeed_jobs'
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/q-Software-Engineer-l-Portland,-OR-jobs.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        next_page_outer = './/link[@rel="next"]'
        next_page_url_outer = response.xpath(next_page_outer).get()
        print(next_page_url_outer)
```

That code yields:

```
<link rel="next" href="/jobs?q=Software+Engineer&amp;l=Portland%2C+OR&amp;start=10">
```

How do I get the text from the href contained within this response?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question.  The answer was:

```
next_page_url_href = response.xpath(next_page_outer).xpath("@href").extract()
```

Comment: Note that if you don't really plan on using `next_page_outer`, you can simplify it into one XPath: `response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').get()`