# how to write css selector for scrapy?

Tags: html, css

I have the following web page:

```
<div id="childcategorylist" class="link-list-container links__listed" data-reactid="7">
    <div data-reactid="8">
        <strong data-reactid="9">Categories</strong>
    </div>
    <div data-reactid="10">
        <ul id="categoryLink" aria-label="shop by category" data-reactid="11">
            <li data-reactid="12">
                <a href="/store/c/contact-lenses/ID=359432-tier2clense" aria-label="Contact Lenses" data-reactid="13">Contact Lenses</a>
            </li>
            <li data-reactid="14">
                <a href="/store/c/beauty/ID=359434-tier1" aria-label="Beauty" data-reactid="15">Beauty</a>
            </li>
            <li data-reactid="16">
                <a href="/store/c/personal-care/ID=359436-tier1" aria-label="Personal Care" data-reactid="17">Personal Care</a>
            </li>
```

I want to have css selector of href tags under li tag, i.e. for contact lens, beauty and personal-care. How to write it?

I am writing it in the following way:

```
#childcategorylist li
```

gives me following output:

```
['<li class="titleitem" data-reactid="16"><strong data-reactid="17">Categories</strong></li>']
```

Please help!

Comment: do you mean code like this? `#childcategorylist li a{some styling}`

Comment: i tried using a::attr(href) as well, but received blank output.

Comment: .attr is javascript/jquery code, are you trying to fetch the href from an achor in css?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert in scrapy, but usually html elements should have a .text object.
If not, you might want to use regexp to extract the text between > and < like:

```
import re
txt = someArraycontainingStrings[0]
x = re.search(">[a-zA-Z]*</", txt)
```

Maybe that gives you proper results

Comment: For the case you are able to use python.
else you might want to try #childcategorylist li::text as mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663463/how-scrapy-extract-text-inside-class-that-inside-attribute

Comment: I tried using it. but there's no link or text defined particularly for the next page. So I can't extract it.